# What is the default Hashset bucket size in Java?

Tags: java, collections, hashset

In collection in Java,What's the default initial size of hashSet?

Comment: A quick google search will lead you to the answer:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#HashSet()

Answer (score 4):

Information like this is usually available in the the Java API https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#HashSet--

**HashSet**

Default initial capacity: 16

Default load factor: 0.75

Answer (score 1):

**16**

A hashset uses a hashmap under the hood. The underlying hashmap uses 16 buckets for its hashing. See the API Doc for hashmap:

[HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Answer (score 0):

**HashSet** -initial capacity (**16**)
load factor (**0.75**)
**HashMap** -initial capacity (**16**)
load factor (**0.75**)
**HashTable** -initial capacity (**11**)
load factor (**0.75**)

Comment: Hi :), please add a little description to your answer.